# How to install properly Stardog on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: stardog

I downloaded and unzipped Stardog and I get the instructions on the site but I'm unable to run it and need to understand what I'm missing:

What I did:

```
export STARDOG_HOME=/data/stardog
```

I downloaded also the key
Then:

```
cp stardog-license-key.bin $STARDOG_HOME
```

Error:

```
cp: /data/stardog: No such file or directory
```

A solution did not work for me I found online:

```
./bin/stardog-admin server start
```

Error:

```
STARDOG_HOME directory '/data/stardog' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's precisely what the error message says, that `/data/stardog` does not exist. The instructions assume you have an existing location where you want the home directory to be, Stardog does not create it. So you should either create that directory, or open a new terminal, don't do the first command, and change the second to `cp stardog-license-key.bin .` That will make Stardog's home directory your current directory, specifically, the root of the binary distribution.